# Not able to create a topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create a topic in Kafka, I installed a fresh copy of Kafka by downloading the .tar from official Apache mirror site.

I used the tar -xvf command to unpack the bundle and started the server, which ran ok.

Now I am trying the command: 
`bin/kafka-create-topic.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replica 1 --partition 1 --topic test`

I tried to dig the problem and actually check if the file was present, somehow the result is negative: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the bin directory so the command should be :

./kafka-create-topic.sh .....

and not

bin/kafka-create-topic.sh

maybe a copy & paste error from the documentation web site ;)

[UPDATE]

even if the directory was wrong, in this case the new Kafka version has changed the script name so the right command is :

kafka-topic.sh --create ...

Comment: The file does not actually exist there, the directory listing `ls` proves that

Comment: In any case it couldn't work but you are right. What is the version you downloaded and the related link ?

Comment: I did a curl on `http://redrockdigimark.com/apachemirror/kafka/0.10.2.0/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.tgz`

Comment: My bad! I was referring to older documentation, the correct command is: `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test` Nevertheless, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to create a topic in Kafka,

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic topic_name
```

For further clarification, visit https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart